# How do I find which dll is causing an error?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Background:

Windows 7 with SQL Server 2012 Data Tools & Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 installed.

Trying to create a new SSIS project in Visual Studio and I get the following error:

[image: The type initializer for Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.SharedIcons threw an exception]
I am almost certain this is being caused by an incorrect dll in 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

Question:
Is there any way to trace which dll's are being loaded by an application at run time?

I also tried:

C:>tasklist /m /fi "imagename eq devenv.exe "

but only get the relatively unhelpful result:

```
Image Name                     PID Modules
========================= ======== ============================================
devenv.exe                    2784 ntdll.dll, wow64.dll, wow64win.dll,
                                   wow64cpu.dll
devenv.exe                    6836 ntdll.dll, wow64.dll, wow64win.dll,
                                   wow64cpu.dll
```

Also, I am aware this is not a Visual Studio issue, but one with SSDT-BI which uses VS as it's shell, but there is no SU tag for SSDT-BI.

Comment: Maybe there is one on StackOverflow?

Comment: Was there any additional information related to the error in the Event Viewer?

Comment: Have you seen this?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2832017

Comment: The description for Event ID 0 from source devenv cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer. 
The data source '{130bada6-e128-423c-9d07-02e4734d45d4}' specifies no supporting providers or a set that are not registered. 
I looked for this in the registry, and it is SQL Server Compact.  Doesn't really help as this is installed.  But more to the point, I am curious about seeing what dll's are being loaded during the project creation process.

Comment: I've had very very bad luck with DB related functions when mixing VS2010 and VS2012 on one Pc. 2012 installs some DLLs over 2010's versions, and does not restore them when you uninstall 2012. I had to rebuild my PC afterwards.

Comment: @heavyd - I have - I should have said, I am currently on 11.1.31009.1 (Oct 2013 update)

Comment: I reinstalled SQL Server compact and the event viewer issues disappeared, but issue persists so they were unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) from Scott Hanselman has several techniques for debugging assembly loading errors.  I would reccommend both the [Fusion Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) approach or the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) approach.

The Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fusion Log Viewer) should be installed if you have Visual Studio installed.  Its installed as part of the Windows SDK.  On my machine the path is: `c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v8.0a\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\FUSLOGVW.exe`  From the "Settings" button you can enable "Log all binds to disk" to enable logging.

Once logging is enabled, create the error and click "Refresh" to see all the assemblies that were loaded.

Comment: You can use the little target icon in Process Explorer to select the window, which will show you which process belongs to the window.

Comment: You answered my question!  - Thank you
Fusion enabled me to get the following.  I will open a new question but if anyone has any idea what this means...LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Business Intelligence Semantic Model/en-US/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHost.11.resources.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.